# Transfer data from one table to another table by SSIS

Tags: etl, ssis, data-transfer, dataflow

I am trying to perform ETL from one table (Table A) to another table (Table B) using SSIS packages.
I have OLE DB Source and OLE DB Destination. But I need to only transfer those rows of Table A which are not present in Table B.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the LookUp component inside your data flow to check table B for data that already exists.

[image: SSIS LookUp component]

The LookUp component NoMatchBehavior property can then be configured (from right click, properties) to "Send rows with no matching entries to the no match output".

When you drag the link to the target table, you will be asked whether you want to use LookUp Match or LookUp No Match

[image: LookUp Match / No Match options]